# Оформление прямой речи в диалоге

Tags: прямая-речь

Как, по-вашему, стоит оформить данную реплику в диалоге?
- Теперь собираем вещи и идем домой, - проговорил Петр Васильевич.
- Он сказал "идем домой"? - шепотом спросил Вася у сестры. 
(Или:
- Он сказал: "...идем домой"?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я бы оформила так.

— Теперь собираем вещи и идем домой, — проговорил Петр Васильевич.
— Он сказал "идем домой"? — шепотом спросил Вася у сестры.

Вот что пишет Розенталь ([§ 52. Знаки препинания при диалоге](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=160)).

Если в последующей реплике повторяются слова из предыдущей реплики, принадлежащей другому лицу, причем они воспринимаются как чужой текст, то эти слова выделяются кавычками:

Силан. *Пройдись малость, лучше тебе…*
Курослепов. *Да, «пройдись малость»! Всё твоё рассмотрение…* (Остр.)

*«Если вы будете свободны, заходите ко мне». — «Как это “будете свободны”? Ведь у меня каждая минута на учёте».*